# Call a python method in record rule Odoo

Tags: odoo

The common syntax of record rules is ['|',('user_id','=',user.id),('user_id','=',False)]]

Is there any possiblilties we can use a python method to get the dynamic ids of user?

For Example

['|',('user_id','=',getuserid()),('user_id','=',False)]

Comment: It should be possible to extend the executable context by adding a method to it, but a easier (and also not so clean way) is to extend model `res.users` with such a method and calling it by `[('user_id', 'in', user.my_new_method_return_id_list())]`.
'

Comment: Oh and i have a question: which odoo version is your question for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like,
xml:

```
['|',('user_id','=', user.env["your.model"].get_userid().id), ('user_id','=',False)]
```

Py:

```
def get_userid(self):
    domain = []
    return self.env["res.user"].search(domain)
```

Let me know if this works for you.